# When i am adding Rigidbody to Particle System it flying to Y axis?

Tags: particle-system, rigid-bodies

I am working on Particle System but one thing i noticed that when in add component i am adding Rigidbody to Particle System it fly to Y axis.

I am not unable to find proper reason for this please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: can you give us some code, then we can check whats wrong

Comment: What language? What library? Where's the code that adds the particle?

Comment: it's a Unity project there is no code for this if you are a unity developer then you should be familiar with this terms..